# Electron input with datalist

Tags: electron, html-datalist

I am facing a problem when I want to read the value of an input that have suggestions from datalist, the value that I get from the input is only what I type with the keyboard not the selected value, i’ll give an example to explain better, for the HTML bellow, if I type ‘on’ than I select the suggestion which is ‘111’ when I try to read the value of the input (document.getElementById(“num”).value) I get ‘on’ instead of ‘111’, any suggestions to fix it??

```html
<input type="text" list="numbrs" id="num">
 <datalist id="numbrs">
  <option value="111">One</option>
  <option value="222">two</option>
 </datalist>
```

Comment: This is only for electron, when I do it on chrome it works fine

Comment: try `document.getElementById(“num”).getAttribute("value")`

Comment: it returns null

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by using SELECT2 and Jquery Autocomplete.